# Is viewing system files like "/sbin/init" safe?

Tags: files, init

Do I risk breaking my installation of Ubuntu if I view `/sbin/init` without editing it, say, in gedit? (I'm taking an online Linux course and they mention this and I wanted to see what it looks like.)

Comment: Yep, it is fine to just view. Make sure when you click close, you don't save any changes you accidentally made.

Comment: Not sure what there is to "view" in `/sbin/init`, since it's a binary file and you'll likely get weird symbols in a text editor, but no, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes. It's safe to view any system file(s), especially if you don't use `sudo` or `root`.**

```
prakhar@aS4v4g3wOrld:~$ ll /sbin/init
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 265848 Jul 18 15:16 /sbin/init*
```

The owner of `/sbin/init` is `root`. The only way you **can** modify this file is either via logging as `root` (`$ sudo -s`) or by giving an editor `superuser` permissions using `sudo`.

Besides, `/sbin/init` is a binary file, not meant for reading. If you still want to view this, use a hex editor like

```
$ sudo apt-get install ghex
$ ghex /sbin/init
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can read it without doing any harm.

It's a binary file - if you are interested in the text in it, like program symbols, messages, or version numbers, use `strings`:

`strings /sbin/init | less`

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
I*|YB
GU1q
nx#$
BDCE
#9ym
libnih.so.1
_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
__gmon_start__
_Jv_RegisterClasses
_ITM_registerTMCloneTable
nih_watch_new
nih_alloc_real_set_destructor
nih_timer_add_timeout
[ ... many more lines ... ]
```

To see the full binary content of the file in a somewhat readable form, use `hexdump`:

`hexdump -C /sbin/init | less`

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  03 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  e9 96 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.............|
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  78 07 04 00 00 00 00 00  |@.......x.......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00  09 00 40 00 1c 00 1b 00  |....@.8...@.....|
00000040  06 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000050  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@.......@.......|
00000060  f8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  f8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |8.......8.......|
00000090  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |8...............|
000000a0  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000b0  01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  1c d7 03 00 00 00 00 00  1c d7 03 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
[ ... many more lines ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it is fine to just view. Make sure when you click close, you don't save any changes you accidentally made.

To be super safe, run the following command:

```
sudo cp /sbin/init /tmp/init.copy
```

then run:

```
sudo gedit /tmp/init.copy
```

So you're not viewing the original.

Comment: May I suggest the `/tmp` directory for copying the file: `cp /sbin/init /tmp/init`

Comment: Yeah, good idea @muru! Wasn't sure where to put it - I didn't want ~ because it's root...

Comment: Many if not most system files are world-readable, including almost all libraries and executables such as `/sbin/init`. It's not necessary to make a copy; opening `/sbin/init` as a non-root user already works, and does not risk accidental modification. If for some reason a copy is made, it is not necessary to do so as root with `sudo`. Furthermore, for a file `foo` with permissions making it unreadable to the user, `sudo cp foo bar` creates a file `bar` that is *also* unreadable. Therefore, might not be much application for the specific technique suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

You can view but you can't make changes. Do not save on exit init. copy the file first with

```
cp /sbin/init /sbin/init.me
```

then run

```
sudo nano /sbin/init.me
```

Here you first make a copy of the original file (`init.me`) then you take a look at `init.me` and find out what you are searching for.

Comment: Is there a way to view the source code somewhere?